# syntax error: `(' unexpected in shell script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a shell script which contains some functions in it. One of those functions has to be executed through perl. The perl functions checks whether port is opened on a remote server or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

function1
function2
telnet_check()
{

#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use IO::Socket;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my ($host,$port);
$host=Ip address ;
$port=9443;
my $sock=IO::Socket::INET->new("Ip address:$port") or die "" ;

}

some shell commands
```

while executing the above script, am getting the error

```
 syntax error at line: `(' unexpected [which falls in the line my ($host,$port); under the Perl function]
```

Could any one help what can be done to fix the above error.

Cheers in Advance :)

Comment: Hey @toolic I already tried like that and it works. But, i want to put it in one script itself. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch from ksh to Perl that easily. Either, quote the script and pass it as a parameter to perl's `-e`:

```
perl -MIO::Socket -MIO::Socket::INET -we 'my ($host, $port) = qw( host.name 9443 ); ...'
```

or, store the perl script in a file of its own, and run it:

```
perl /path/to/the/script.pl
```

or, send the script to the stdin of `perl` - only works if you don't need to read input from within the script.

```
cat <<'EOF' | perl
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Socket::INET;
...
EOF
```

Comment: am getting error while trying in the last way.                                                                 syntax error at line 10 : `<<' unmatched

Comment: @Su_scriptingbee: Are you sure the closing `EOF` is alone on the line, i.e. no whitespace around it?

Comment: There was a space between EOF and closing brace. I corrected it now and it works fine :) Thanks a lot